# Getting wrong answer while trying to solve Best sum problem using Dynamic programming

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

Trying to solve the best sum problem but I'm not getting the right answer using DP but if I remove the memoization part of this code then I'm getting the right answer.

I'm attaching the output screenshots:

[image]

PS: Please do not judge my code I'm trying to learn DP and I know that this code is not the best.

```
public class BestSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int num = 10;
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<Integer> list = rec(arr, num, map);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    static List<Integer> rec(int[] arr, int n, Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map) {

        if (n == 0) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if (n < 0) {
            return null;
        }
        if (map.containsKey(n)) {
            return map.get(n);
        }
        List<Integer> sCombo = null;
        for (int i : arr) {
            int rem = n - i;
            List<Integer> t = rec(arr, rem, map);
            if (t != null) {
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                t.add(i);
                list.addAll(t);
                if (sCombo == null || list.size() < sCombo.size()) {
                    sCombo = list;
                }

            }
        }

        map.put(n, sCombo);
        return map.get(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Best Sum` problem?  Don't assume all is aware of this problem.

Comment: Sorry for that.
Given an array of distinct integers arr and a target integer num, return a list of numbers is smallest and where the chosen numbers sum to target. You may return the combinations in any order.
e.g. : 
arr = { 2, 3, 4, 5 }
num = 10

output : [5,5]

Comment: Still confused by the explanation and output - `[5, 5]`  The input arr only has one `5`!  If it allows to re-use any numbers in `arr` then the ans. could be [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 2, 3] ....

Comment: So you have to return minimum size array such that the sum of each element of output array is the number in this case 10 and you can reuse elements from original array...
So even though [2,3,5] and [2,3,3,2] sums up to 10 but we can still get the minimum sized array [5,5]  that sums up to 10.

Comment: Ah, it's finally clear to us. Wish you can update all the details your original Post.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that. I'm quite new to posting questions here. 
So do you know what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

list.add(i); // write this instead of t.add(i).

a little mistake in the code nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

just small mistake i.e....
you directly inserting sCombo into the Map. the values in sCombo array was changing while recursion every time at the same time the same sCombo array values in the map also changing because there have only one block of memory for each sCombo array that means when ever we edit that sCombo array it will effects the previous result....

example:- you assigned the list to sCombo
sCombo=list;

when ever the list gets changes then the sCombo also changed

just clone() the object you get correct result like this......